# Using setFieldValue to send different values based button click

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to send a different value of `requestStatuses` (i.e. 10) in the `handleSubmit` callback when a user clicks `Save and Continue` button which is in the formik form as shown below:

```
 <div className="form-field">
         <Button size="large" 
                variant="contained" 
                color="primary"  
                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} 
                type="submit">
                Save & Continue
        </Button>
     </div>
```

FYI: When a user hits `Submit` button, I want to keep the value of `requestStatuses` as `6` which is in this line of the code `props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.statusId || '6',`.:

**Things that I have tried:**

**Scenario 1:**

I was planning of using `setFieldValue` of formik to change the value to `10` like this

```
setFieldValue ('requestStatuses',10,false);
```

and for this I modified the `Save and Continue` button as follows:

```
           <Button size="large" 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"  
                    style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} 
                    type="button"
                    onClick={handleSaveAndContinue}>
                    Save & Continue
            </Button>
```

1. Changed the type of button to `button` from `submit`
2. Defined an `onClick` handler and called a separate function `handleSaveAndContinue`
3. Defined `handleSaveAndContinue` like following and tried to call submitForm prop but nothing happens:

   ```
   const handleSaveAndContinue = () => {

      setFieldValue ('requestStatuses',10,false);
      props.submitForm;

    }
   ```

In this case I did try to include `setFieldValue` as second parameter in `handleSubmit` like following:

```
 handleSubmit(values,{setFieldValue} {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
        props.handleSubmit(values)
        setSubmitting(false)
    },
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
 <Button size="large" 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"  
                    style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} 
                    type="button"
                    onClick={props.submitForm}>
                    Save & Continue
            </Button>
```

1. Changed the type of button to `button` from `submit`
2. Defined an onClick handler and called `submitForm` props onclick.

This does trigger the `handleSubmit` callback but I don't understand where to define `setFieldValue ('requestStatuses',10,false);` in this case.

Am I proceeding with the usage of `setFieldValue` correctly to achieve my goal?

**Minimal Code of Child component with relavent Formik form information:**

```
  const SimpleRequestForm = (props) => {

    const {values, setFieldValue, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleReset, handleChange} = 
     props;
    const growl = React.createRef()
  

    return (
        <div>
           
            <div id="formDiv">
                <Growl ref={growl}/>
                <Form className="form-column-3">
                <div className="SimpleRequest-form">                    
                            

                            <div className="form-field">
                                <CustomSelectField name="requestStatuses" disabled type="select"  placeholder="Status"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-field">
                                <CustomSelectField name="requestPrioritieses" type="select" value='Normal'  placeholder="Priority"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-field">
                                <CustomSelectField name="assignees" type="select"  placeholder="Assignee"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-field">
                                <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"  style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="submit">Save & Continue</Button>
                            </div>
                            
                    </div>


                    <div className="btn-group-right">
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"
                                type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleReset}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Reset</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.onCancel}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Cancel</Button>       
                      
                       
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

     };

     export const SimpleRequestEnhancedForm = withFormik(
    
    
    
    {

        
    mapPropsToValues: props => {

              
        
        return {
            requestId: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.requestId || '',
            requestStatuses: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.statusId || '6',
            requestPrioritieses: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.priorityId || '3',
            assignees: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.assigneeId || '',
                     
        }
    },
    validationSchema:validationSchema,
    handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
          
        props.handleSubmit(values)
        setSubmitting(false)
    },
    setFieldValue(field, value, shouldVal) {
        console.log('In setFieldValue')
    },

    displayName: 'Simple Request Form',
      })(SimpleRequestForm)
```

**Testing Results based on comment:**

My function:

```
const handleSaveAndContinue = () => {

   setFieldValue ('requestStatuses',10,false);
   props.submitForm();

 }
```

**My Button:**

```
<Button size="large" 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary"  
                    style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} 
                    type="button"
                    onClick={handleSaveAndContinue}>
                    Save & Continue
            </Button>
```

My `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(values,{setFieldValue}, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
        props.handleSubmit(values)
        props.setFieldValue()
        setSubmitting(false)
    },
```

Error Received : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ref6 is undefined`. Debugger shows the following:

```
handleSubmit: function handleSubmit(values, _ref5, _ref6) {
    var setFieldValue = _ref5.setFieldValue;
    var props = _ref6.props,
        resetForm = _ref6.resetForm,
        setErrors = _ref6.setErrors,
        setSubmitting = _ref6.setSubmitting;
  
    props.handleSubmit(values); 
    props.setFieldValue();
    setSubmitting(false);
  },
```

Comment: In you implementation of `handleSaveAndContinue` you need to execute the function by plaing braces in the end. So `props.submitForm;` should be changed to `props.submitForm();`

Comment: In your implementation of `handleSubmit` I am guessing you are missing a comma between 2nd and 3rd argument. So it should be: `handleSubmit(values,{setFieldValue},{props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}){ /*some code*/ }`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried `props.submitForm()` and had my `handleSubmit` like you mentioned `handleSubmit(values,{setFieldValue},{props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}){ /*some code*/ }` and it didn't work. I get this error while using `{setFieldValue}`  `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ref6 is undefined`.

Comment: Do I need to return something after using `{setFieldValue}` in `handleSubmit` ?

Comment: I have updated my post with more details about the error.

Comment: The handle submit you have written to mapStateToProps shows definition something like `this : handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) { /*some code*/ }` 
there is no 3rd argument. could be the reason why _ref6 is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243350/discussion-between-mujeeb-qureshi-and-tan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you can do is to keep both of button ('Save and Continue' and 'Submit') types as submit, attach an onClick handler to setFieldValue modifying the values based off of the button that was clicked!

```
<button
    size="large"
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    type="submit"
    onClick={() => {
        props.setFieldValue("requestStatuses", 6, false);
    }}
>
Submit
</button>
```

and

```
<button
    size="large"
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
    type="submit"
    onClick={() => {
        props.setFieldValue("requestStatuses", 10, false);
    }}
>
Save & Continue
</button>
```